# Extract rows from spreadsheet and put into multiple spreadsheets

Tags: excel, vba

I want to loop through a folder with Excel files and for each file, loop through each row (starting at row 4) and for each row, look at what value is in column "d" and paste that row into a particular Excel file named whatever the value in column "d" was.

- If the file doesn't exist, it would need to be created before pasting the row (start at row 4 when pasting). The file name of the newly created file would be whatever value was in column "d".
- If the file exists, the row being copied would be appended (value of column d in given row).

My code doesn't want to loop through all the files.

```
Sub CopyRowsIntoAppSpreadsheet()

Dim LastRow As Integer, i As Integer, erow As Integer
Dim AppFileName As String
Dim FilePath As String
Dim MyFolder As String
Dim MyFile As String
Dim wbk As Workbook

On Error Resume Next

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)

    .Title = "Please select a folder"
    .Show
    .AllowMultiSelect = False

    If .SelectedItems.Count = 0 Then 'If no folder is selected, abort
        MsgBox "You did not select a folder"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    MyFolder = .SelectedItems(1) & "\" 'Assign selected folder to MyFolder

End With

MyFile = Dir(MyFolder) 'DIR gets the first file of the folder

'Loop through all files in a folder until DIR cannot find anymore

Do While MyFile <> “”

    'Opens the file and assigns to the wbk variable for future use
    Set wbk = Workbooks.Open(FileName:=MyFolder & MyFile)

    'Replace the line below with the statements you would want your macro to perform
    LastRow = ActiveSheet.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 4 To LastRow

        Range("d" & i).Select
        AppFileName = Selection.Value
        Rows(i).Select
        Selection.Copy
        FilePath = "C:\Users\Gary\Desktop\Ex Folder\" & AppFileName & ".xlsx"

        If Not Dir(FilePath, vbDirectory) = vbNullString Then
            Workbooks.Open FileName:=FilePath
            Worksheets("Sheet1").Select
            erow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
            ActiveSheet.Cells(erow, 1).Select
            ActiveSheet.Paste
            Cells.Select
            Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
            ActiveWorkbook.Save
            ActiveWorkbook.Close
            Application.CutCopyMode = False

        Else
            Dim wkb As Workbook
            Set wkb = Workbooks.Add
            Rows(4).Select
            ActiveSheet.Paste
            wkb.SaveAs FileName:=FilePath
            Cells.Select
            Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
            ActiveWorkbook.Save
            ActiveWorkbook.Close
            Application.CutCopyMode = False

        End If

    Next i

    MyFile = Dir 'DIR gets the next file in the folder

Loop

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

MsgBox "Macro has completed! Woot! Woot!"

End Sub
```

Comment: So it works, but doesn't loop through all the files?  I confess, I don't normally use the dir(myfolder) thing, but I'll test this out and see if I can help.

Comment: Right now it's only looping through the last file twice and then closing out of the main loop to end the program. I don't have any files (based on value of column d) created in the destination folder. I just wanted the macro to create them.

Comment: I'll make that change. I really appreciate it! Yeah biggest problem at the moment is that it only loops through one or two files and then it stops.

Comment: It's going to the very last file in my folder list which is why it's stopping after the first file.

Comment: The row loop appears to be working fine. It's the folder loop that seems to be the issue.

Comment: It seems like when the column d value files aren't created it only does one row of the last file and then just stops or gets hung up.  Also I thought you just commented becasue a new one came up on my phone but it disappeared?

Comment: I'm sneaking up on it.  I found a version that works here (http://www.exceltrick.com/formulas_macros/vba-dir-function/).  Now I'm gradually rebuilding yours and testing.  I think it might have to do with the nested Dir function call, but I'm not there yet.  This is fun!

Comment: It breaks when you make the second Dir call, even if it's in a subroutine.  I have other code to step through files.  I'll upload it in a little while.

Comment: Haha thank you for your help.i'm glad this is fun for you. It is fun for me too but  even better when it works. Sounds good!

Answer (score 0):

OK, try this:

```
Option Explicit
Sub CopyRowsIntoAppSpreadsheet()
Dim LastRow As Integer, erow As Integer, Rowcounter As Long
Dim AppFileName As String
Dim FilePath As String
Dim MyFolder As String
Dim MyFile As String
Dim Source As Workbook, shSource As workseet, Dest As Workbook, shDest As Worksheet
On Error Resume Next
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
.Title = "Please select a folder"
.Show
.AllowMultiSelect = False
If .SelectedItems.Count = 0 Then 'If no folder is selected, abort
    MsgBox "You did not select a folder"
    Exit Sub
End If
MyFolder = .SelectedItems(1) & "\" 'Assign selected folder to MyFolder
End With
MyFile = Dir(MyFolder) 'DIR gets the first file of the folder
'Loop through all files in a folder until DIR cannot find anymore
Do Until MyFile = ""
    DoEvents
    Set Source = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=MyFolder & MyFile)
    Set shSource = Source.Sheets(1)
    LastRow = shSource.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    For Rowcounter = 4 To LastRow
        'get the name of the workbook to copy to
        AppFileName = Source.Cells(Rowcounter, 4)
        FilePath = "C:\Users\Gary\Desktop\Ex Folder\" & AppFileName & ".xlsx"
        'and open it
        If FileExists(FilePath) Then
            Set Dest = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=FilePath)
        Else
            Set Dest = Workbooks.Add
        End If
        Set shDest = Dest.Sheets(1)
        'get the bottom row of the destination sheet
        erow = shDest.Cells(shDest.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        shSource.Cells(Rowcounter, 1).EntireRow.Copy Destination:=shDest.Cells(erow + 1, 1)
        Dest.SaveAs Filename:=FilePath
        Dest.Close
    'continue with next row
    Next Rowcounter
    Source.Close
    'repeat for next file
    MyFile = Dir()  'DIR gets the next file in the folder
Loop
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
MsgBox "Macro has completed! Woot! Woot!"
End Sub
Function FileExists(FilePath As String) As Boolean
Dim FSO As Object
Dim sFile As String
Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
If Not FSO.FileExists(FilePath) Then
    FileExists = False
Else
    FileExists = True
End If
End Function
```

Comment: i'll test it now.

Comment: No I don't. I'm pretty new to Excel VBA.

Comment: Thank you very much. I'm going to resume this either later today or tomorrow. I'll be sure to get back to you. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I dropped the misused `On Error Resume Next` and replaced the ActiveWorkbook and ActiveSheet references. This would be sufficient most of the time.

Here it appears the second use of Dir interferes with the first so test the existence of the workbook a different way.

```
Option Explicit

Sub CopyRowsIntoAppSpreadsheet()

Dim LastRow As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim erow As Long

Dim AppFileName As String
Dim FilePath As String
Dim MyFolder As String
Dim MyFile As String

Dim wbk As Workbook
Dim wbkTarget As Workbook

Dim sht As Worksheet

'On Error Resume Next   ' Misused here

'Application.ScreenUpdating = False

With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)

    .Title = "Please select a folder"
    .Show
    .AllowMultiSelect = False

    If .SelectedItems.Count = 0 Then 'If no folder is selected, abort
        MsgBox "You did not select a folder"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    MyFolder = .SelectedItems(1) & "\" 'Assign selected folder to MyFolder
    Debug.Print MyFolder

End With

MyFile = Dir(MyFolder) 'DIR gets the first file of the folder

'Loop through all files in a folder until DIR cannot find anymore
'Do While MyFile <> “”
Do While MyFile <> ""

    'Opens the file and assigns to the wbk variable for future use
    Set wbk = Workbooks.Open(FileName:=MyFolder & MyFile)

    LastRow = wbk.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 4 To LastRow

        Range("d" & i).Select
        AppFileName = Selection.Value

        Rows(i).Select
        Selection.Copy

        FilePath = "C:\Users\Gary\Desktop\Ex Folder\" & AppFileName & ".xlsx"

        ' Reset wbkTarget or
        '  the tricky On Error Resume Next keeps the previous valid wbkTarget
        Set wbkTarget = Nothing
        On Error Resume Next
        Set wbkTarget = Workbooks.Open(FileName:=FilePath)
        ' turn off error bypass as soon as the purpose is served
        On Error GoTo 0

        If Not wbkTarget Is Nothing Then

            Set sht = wbkTarget.Worksheets("Sheet1")
            erow = sht.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row

            With sht
                .Cells(erow, 1).Select
                .Paste
                .Cells.Select
                .Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
            End With

            wbkTarget.Close True

         Else ' Address the bypassed error

            Set wbkTarget = Workbooks.Add
            Set sht = wbkTarget.Worksheets("Sheet1")

            With sht
                .Rows(4).Select
                .Paste
                .Cells.Select
                .Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
            End With

            With wbkTarget
                .SaveAs FileName:=FilePath
                .Close
            End With

        End If

        Application.CutCopyMode = False

    Next i

    wbk.Close False

    MyFile = Dir 'DIR gets the next file in the folder
    Debug.Print MyFile

Loop

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

MsgBox "Macro has completed."

End Sub
```